# d3js - Zoom linearGradient hoizontally; hiding the vertical scaling

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, zooming

I am building a d3js chart that plots some dots on a gradient scale of agree to disagree. I need it to be able to zoom and pan and I have all of that working except for a rectangle holding a linearGradient. The gradient zooms just as I need it, but it scales up both horizontally AND vertically, expanding past the original 20px height:

[image]

Or shrinking excessively:

[image]

I tried to use a clip path which is clearly not working, it seems that the clip path scales with the gradient. How can I clamp the rectangle to the axis and keep it the same size?

Here is my [block](https://bl.ocks.org/Ognami/12cf0f4edd245ac394c36f99262a53e9)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two primary challenges from what I can see:

- the rectangle filled with the gradient scales on the y axis as you note.
- the clip path isn't working as intended.

Let's drop the clip path, that'll make things a bit easier. Secondly, let's not scale the rectangle at all when we zoom (we can keep the translate that is applied though).

---

Now that I've destroyed what we had, let's build it back up.

Instead of scaling the rectangle with `transform(scale())` let's modify its width directly. If `d3.event.transform.k` is the factor at which we were scaling (both x and y), let's just modify the width of the rectangle. Instead of:

```
gradientScale
  .attr("transform","translate("+d3.event.transform.x+","+(height- spacer*3)+")scale("+d3.event.transform.k+")");
```

Let's use:

```
gradientScale
  .attr("transform", "translate( " +d3.event.transform.x+ " , " + (height - spacer*3) + ")")
  .attr("width", width * d3.event.transform.k);
```

By removing the scaling, the above won't warp any coordinates, which won't lead to stretching of the y axis. It doesn't modify any y coordiantes, so the bar stays where it is height wise with the same height.

It does modify the width - by the same amount we were scaling it before (*the rectangle's width at k = 1 is `width`*). This achieves the stretching of the scale as we zoom in. The x translate factor is unchanged.

Here's a [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/52415d01d25f06330d9d20c00e6b4e80) of the modified code.

*My initial thought before looking closely was to try a completely different approach. So, for comparison, [here's](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/3b57476f1686486242ad65ae2fcd551a) a completely different approach modifying the axis itself.*

Comment: I did not even think of that but that is a great solution!! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, I hope you don't mind, I added a few visuals to the question and modified it slightly - I hope that it is a bit clearer but still keeps the original intent.